# How to stop Linux from automatically unmounting CD Drive right before shutdown

Tags: boot, shutdown, bios, pop-os, unmounting

I am using Pop OS on my laptop and whenever I poweroff, it automatically unmounts the CD drive. As a result every time I turn on the laptop the CD drive gets stuck in a loop of making a small noise it normally makes when it is automatically being mounted by the BIOS (in a normal situation it only makes that noise once when the computer is booting up but with Pop OS it continues to infinitely make that noise in a loop).

Right now the only way to stop this is to manually hold the power button right after I turn on the laptop in order to turn the laptop off and turn it back on again. However the problem reoccurs if I shutdown via Pop OS.

Notice that this problem does not occur after a suspend, hibernation or reboot. It only occurs after a poweroff.

So I think the way to stop this for good is to change something in the system files in order to stop Linux from unmounting the CD drive while it is shutting down.

Comment: When you say "_unmount_" do you actually mean "_eject_"? I would say that one is a software process and the other is a hardware action

Comment: No I meant safety remove (software process "unmount") not physical ejection. It's when you hit shutdown and the OS runs a bunch of commands before the device is fully off. I am not 100% sure if unmounting is the reason why the loop happens the next time I turn on the computer but as I said earlier if I manually turn off the computer it fixes it. The noise that the CD drive makes is the same noise that it makes when it also wants to begin reading a disk i.e. a CD or DVD.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: the noise it makes `when it is automatically being mounted by the BIOS` will still occur (despite your claims otherwise), since the BIOS would have no clue if the CD is mounted or not in an operating system that is yet to be booted ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ mounting a CD is not a physical thing, so there's no indication outside of linux if the disk is mounted or not

Comment: No it's like trying to read a CD that is not there continuously in a loop. I think it's the sound of CD drive's head moving but as I said earlier under normal circumstances it only makes that sound once when the system is booting up not in a loop. It also makes that sound once when I insert a CD to be read by the drive.